# Creating multiple instance of same vector

Tags: c++, vector

for a project I'm working on I would like to have a sort of "per user" vector for struct objects.

So, I have done this to declare the vector:

```
// Defined in global namespace, and the pointer to structure objects is deliberate
typedef std::vector<s_AttachmentData*> AttachmentsContainer; 

struct s_User 
{
public: 
    AttachmentsContainer attachmentsData; 
};
```

I'm able to add such structure objects to the vector without issue. I'm struggling to actually access and modify the data through an iterator. Here is what I've tried:

```
// 'p' is pointer to s_User structure above
for (AttachmentsContainer::iterator it = p->attachmentsData.begin(); it != p->attachmentsData.end(); ++it)
{
   // Do stuff here, however I can't get to this point because the application crashes. 
}
```

I'm trying to merely access the data in the container, I'm able to populate the vectors but when I loop and attempt to access anything I'm getting a "vector iterators incompatible" error. If anyone can relate to this, or can push me in the right direction I would be greatly indebted! I could not find any similar issues anywhere, oddly.

Comment: What 'stuff' are you doing exactly? What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Provide a good [MCVE].

Comment: @cawfee: The idea is that you post the code which doesn't work, and copy & paste the error message into the question. This makes it easier to find the information for future readers, and of course it also makes it easier to answer the question.

Comment: I'm new here, and sorry for that. That code in fact does not work. I will edit the first post to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

`*it` will get you a reference to `s_AttachmentData*`.

If you really meant to store pointers to `s_AttachmentData`, then you can access those with something like

```
    (*it)->...
```